# Removing an array of unwanted words from a string

Tags: javascript, replace

I have an array of 'garbage words' that I want to remove from a list of terms.

The goal is to find the most frequently occurring terms in a job advertisement. I want to find actual text, and strip out words like "function", "and", "or", "a", etc.

This will be incorporated into a bookmarklet.

The script I have, strips out some of them, but not all!

I have tried all of the suggested links on StackOverflow and so far, all have come up short - I'm probably missing something, but am out of ideas.

```
javascript:var page=window.location.href;
var counts={};
var text=document.body.textContent||document.body.innerText||'';

var garbageString = ["of", "the", "in", "on", "at", "to", "a", "is", "and", "function", "open", "drop", "be"];
var text = text.split(" ");
for(var i=0; i < garbageString.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j < text.length; j++){
        if(text[j].toLowerCase() === garbageString[i]){
            text.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}
text = text.join(" ");


var words=text.split(/\b/).filter(function(word){return word.match(/^\w+$/)!==null});

words.forEach(function(word){counts['_'+word.toLowerCase()]=(counts['_'+word]||0)+1});
var sorted=Object.keys(counts).sort(function(a,b){return counts[b]-counts[a]});
var message=sorted[0]===undefined?'No words found!':'<center><b>For the page: <i><font color=\"#0000FF\" size=\"-2\">'+page+'<\/i><\/font><br\/>The Top 20 words are:<\/center><\/b><br>';
sorted.forEach(function(word,index){
if(index>19||word===undefined)return;message+='\n#'+(index+1)+': '+word.substring(1)+' ('+counts[word]+' occurrences)<br>'});
w=window.open('','Word Mode','scrollbars,resizable,width=250,height=500');
w.document.write(message);
```

When I test the bookmarklet on an URL such as this:

https://jobs.jpmorganchase.com/ShowJob/Id/208140/VP,%20Software%20Engineering%20%E2%80%93%20Agile%20Coach

I would like to see a list of terms which relate to the job ad and skills; 
not this:

1. to (51 occurrences)
2. and (43 occurrences)
3. function (29 occurrences)
4. a (28 occurrences)
5. open (28 occurrences)
6. drop (28 occurrences)
7. of (20 occurrences)
8. be (19 occurrences)
9. var (14 occurrences)
10. is (14 occurrences)

Answer (score 0):

Use filter.

```
var text=document.body.textContent||document.body.innerText||'';

var garbageString = ["of", "the", "in", "on", "at", "to", "a", "is", "and", "function", "open", "drop", "be"];

var words = text.split(" ");

var filteredWords = words.filter(function(word) {
   return garbageString.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) === -1;
}).sort();
```

Comment: Thanks - but I still get the garbage string. Here's what I got with that solution:

The Top 20 words are:
`
#1: var (51 occurrences)
#2: a (36 occurrences)
#3: function (32 occurrences)
#4: return (31 occurrences)
#5: 1 (28 occurrences)
#6: 0 (28 occurrences)
#7: clc (27 occurrences)
#8: of (21 occurrences)
#9: and (19 occurrences)
#10: document (18 occurrences)
`

Comment: There was a small syntax error, but I somehow found & fixed it. :) 

`var garbageString = ["of", "the", "in", "on", "at", "to", "a", "is", "and", "function", "open", "drop", "be"];
`
`var words = text.split(" ");
`
`var filteredWords = words.filter(function(word) {
 `  return garbageString.indexOf(word.toLowerCase() !== -1);
`});
`

Comment: Yeah. I made a couple mistakes. Updating the answer low.